# Python - operations out of order

Tags: python, tkinter

The below code is supposed to throw up the specified tkMessagebox when the button is pressed (eg. if update_cost button is pressed before an item is selected, it will throw up an error. HOWEVER, it is currently only showing up after I press the OK button after pressing the update_cost.

Can anyone see what i've done wrong? Cheers. (Code sample below).

```
def update_name(self, new_name):
    key=self.get_key_from_selection()  
    if key == None:  
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Name","No item selected.")
    else:  
        self.products.get_item(key).set_name(new_name)  
        self.refresh_listbox()


def update_cost(self, new_cost):  
    key=self.get_key_from_selection()  
    if key!=None:  
        item=self.products.get_item(key)  
        if item.get_type()==PART:  
            if new_cost.isdigit():  
                item.set_cost(int(new_cost))  
                self.refresh_listbox()  
            else:  
                tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Cost","Your input should be a number.")  
        else:  
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Cost","Action: 'Update_Cost' cannot be performed on a compound item.")  
    else:  
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Cost","No item selected.")  

def update_items(self, new_items_list):  
    key=self.get_key_from_selection()  
    if key!=None:  
        item=self.products.get_item(key)  
        if item.get_type()==COMPOUND:  
            # In order to use the internal methods of compound class to check the format and dependence, a temporary compound will recieve new list first before add to the products list..  
            temp=Compound('temp','',self.products,[])  
            try:  
                temp.set_items(new_items_list)  
            except:  
                tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Items","Invalid Items List.")  
                return  
            do=True  
            # Check all the items in the new list to ensure them not conflict any conditions below, or the add operation will not be done.  
            for sub_item in temp.get_depend():  
                if sub_item not in self.products.get_keys():  
                    tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Items","There is at least one item not in the products list.")  
                    do=False  
                    break  
                elif sub_item==item.get_ID():  
                    tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Items","The item could not refer to the compound itself.")  
                    do=False  
                    break  
            if do:  
                item.set_items(new_items_list)  
                self.refresh_listbox()  
        else:  
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Items","Invalid Items List.")  
    else:  
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Update Items","No item selected.")  

def push_remove_item(self):  
    key=self.get_key_from_selection()  
    if key!=None:  
        if not self.products.check_depend(key):  
            self.products.remove_item(key)      
            self.refresh_listbox()  
        else:  
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Remove Item","Selected item contained in compound item.")     
    else:  
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Remove Item","No item selected.")  

# Controller part:  

class Controller(object):  
    # This class organise all the controllers in the window.  
    def __init__(self, window):  
        # Initialise the View object.  
        self.view=View(window)  
        self.view.pack(side=TOP, ipady=130)  

        # Initialise the menu.   
        self.menu_bar=Menu(window)  
        window['menu']=self.menu_bar  
        self.file_menu=Menu(self.menu_bar)  
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=self.file_menu)  
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='Open Products File', command=self.view.push_open_file)  
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='Save Products File', command=self.view.push_save_file)  
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=exit)  

        # Initialise the function buttons, using a Frame to container layout them.  
        self.control_bar=Frame(window, width=150)  
        self.control_bar.pack(side=TOP, pady=10)  
        self.add_part_button=Button(self.control_bar, text="Add Part", command=self.push_add_part)  
        self.add_part_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, anchor=CENTER)  
        self.add_compound_button=Button(self.control_bar, text="Add Compound", command=self.push_add_compound)  
        self.add_compound_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, anchor=CENTER)  
        self.update_name_button=Button(self.control_bar, text="Update Name", command=self.push_update_name)  
        self.update_name_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, anchor=CENTER)  
        self.update_cost_button=Button(self.control_bar, text="Update Cost", command=self.push_update_cost)  
        self.update_cost_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, anchor=CENTER)  
        self.update_items_button=Button(self.control_bar, text="Update Items", command=self.push_update_items)  
        self.update_items_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, anchor=CENTER)  
        self.remove_item_button=Button(self.control_bar, text="Remove Item", command=self.view.push_remove_item)  
        self.remove_item_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, anchor=CENTER)  

        # Initialise the entry area in the botttom, using a Frame to container layout them.  
        self.entry_area=Frame(window, width=150)  
        self.entry_area.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=10)  
        self.status=Label(self.entry_area, width=20)  
        self.status.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0, anchor=CENTER)  
        self.entry=Entry(self.entry_area, width=80)  
        self.entry.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0, anchor=CENTER)  
        self.OK_button=Button(self.entry_area, text="OK", command=self.push_OK)  
        self.OK_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, anchor=CENTER)  

    # The next 5 methods will be activated after their corresponded buttons are pushed, the actions of them are to change the commandID variable and label text.  
    # The function of this variable is to set the function statue before typing in the entry box.  

    def push_add_part(self):  
        self.commandID=ADD_PART  
        self.status.config(text="Add Part ID")  

    def push_add_compound(self):  
        self.commandID=ADD_COMPOUND  
        self.status.config(text="Add Compound ID")  

    def push_update_name(self):  
        self.commandID=UPDATE_NAME  
        self.status.config(text="Update Name")  

    def push_update_cost(self):  
        self.commandID=UPDATE_COST  
        self.status.config(text="Update Cost")  

    def push_update_items(self):  
        self.commandID=UPDATE_ITEMS  
        self.status.config(text="Update Compound Items")          

    # The operations setted beofre will only be done after OK button pushed.   
    def push_OK(self):  
        if self.commandID==ADD_PART:  
            self.view.add_part(self.entry.get())  
        elif self.commandID==ADD_COMPOUND:  
            self.view.add_compound(self.entry.get())  
        elif self.commandID==UPDATE_NAME:  
            self.view.update_name(self.entry.get())  
        elif self.commandID==UPDATE_COST:  
            self.view.update_cost(self.entry.get())  
        elif self.commandID==UPDATE_ITEMS:  
            self.view.update_items(self.entry.get())  
        # Clear the label box.  
        self.status.config(text='')  
        # Clear the entry box.  
        self.entry.delete(0, END)  
        # Reset the command statue.  
        self.commandID=None
```

Comment: Is there some missing code at the top?  Those first functions look to be methods of a class.

Comment: You _need_ to reduce this down to the _bare minimum_ that displays your problem. It's a lot easier to focus on the issue when you don't have to wade through so much irrelevancy. It's even more helpful if you include enough code for your example to run.

Comment: As far as I can see it actually does what you told him to do. When you hit any button other then the OK button, e.g. update_cost, you just set the commandID, but not calling any of the methods from the view, which would actually do the validation and throw an error. View methods are called only when you press the OK button, inside the push_OK method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined your "update_cost" button like this:

```
self.update_cost_button=Button(..., command=self.push_update_cost)  
...
def push_update_cost(self):  
    self.commandID=UPDATE_COST  
    self.status.config(text="Update Cost")
```

Notice that nowhere in `push_update_cost()` do you actually call the code that would generate the error. The error is generated by the `update_cost` method on the view, but that method is only called from `push_OK`, and `push_OK` is only called as a response to clicking on the OK button.